# How to scroll the text in a RichTextBox to a particular prhase?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a RichTextBox that conatins text and after text loaded I want the scroller to show the particular phrase that i get dinamycally.

Example: I want to scroll to "And thanks again pal!" which is at the end of my text and if I dont know that it is there I have scrool all the way down.

I was wondering if there is a way in .net that thing to happen without scrolling?

Answer (score 2):

First you'll need to find the index of that phrase:

```
var index = richTextBox.Text.IndexOf("my phrase");
```

and then you'll need to set the `SelectionStart` to that index:

```
richTextBox.SelectionStart = index;
```

so now the text box is in the right position, now you can do this:

```
richTextBox.ScrollToCaret();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        rtb_Log.Text = "This text is not so special.";
        string findstring = "special.";
        rtb_Log.Select(rtb_Log.Find(findstring, RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase), 0);
        rtb_Log.Focus();
```

Valid for .net 4.0 winforms control.

Comment: rtb_Log.Focus() may be needed in case if any other control will catch the focus instead

Comment: There is no such a property .Text for a RichTextBox control in WPF

Comment: Sorry didn't know that your question is refered to WPF.
 Please change tag winforms to WPF in your question.